# Как правильно использовать сочетание "открыть глаза" с последующими словами?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Открыл ей глаза на..." или "раскрыл ей глаза..."?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы *имеете в виду* то, что девушке рассказали, или дали понять, что более верно, то здесь может употребляться только предлог "на". Например:

**Я открыл ей глаза на истинные причины.**

Answer (score 1):

Существуют оба выражения: ***открыть глаза* и *раскрыть глаза* (кому на кого, на что).**

Отличаются они, скорее всего, **значением глагола**: ***открыть глаза*** — это просто вывести из заблуждения, помочь правильно понять что-либо, а ***раскрыть глаза*** — это дать разностороннюю информацию по этой теме.

[https://phraseology.academic.ru/8086/Открывать_глаза](https://phraseology.academic.ru/8086/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0)

[https://phraseology.academic.ru/10568/Раскрыть_глаза](https://phraseology.academic.ru/10568/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0)